# How to differentiate this equation

Tags: calculus

I want to differentiate

$\frac{-\Delta N}{T(1+e^{\frac{-\Delta}{k_B T}})}$ and I'm finding it quite difficult! It's a product rule, and I think the first term is

$\frac{\Delta N}{T^2 (1+e^{-\frac{\Delta}{k_B T}})}$

From differentiating the $\frac{1}{T}$.

But then I'm finding the next term hard to calculate, where you differentiate the $\frac{1}{(1+e^{-\frac{\Delta}{k_B T}})}$. I gave it a go but arrived at a completely different answer to Wolfram Alpha. Could someone show me the steps?

All other variables in the equation are not dependent on T.

Comment: sounds like Arrhenius thermionic emission equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\frac1T =u ,\,  k= \dfrac{-\Delta}{k_B} ;$

Then you get the function to be differentiated  into form

$$ \dfrac {u }{1+ e^{k u}} $$

by Quotient Rule

$$ \dfrac {u }{1+ e^{k u}} = \dfrac {1 }{k e^{k u}}$$

with maximum/minimum occurring at

$$e^k ( u k -1 ) -1 =0 $$

since $T$ and $\frac1T$ are monotonous, maximum/minimum interchangeably occur at same $T$ point.

The above transcendental equation is to be further solved numerically or graphically.